# how to verify truth table of MAX485/RS485

Tags: rs485, truth-table

I want verify 2nd case of the below truth table of MAX485 IC (RS485). Please see in red color.[image]

Is my circuit correct ? I have connected RE,DE and A-B to GND for making it LOW.I have connect DI to GND also just to avoid floating connection. However LED still unexpectedly blinks. why?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcpdrn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

what is wrong in my cicuit?

thanks

Comment: This is basically same as your previous question?

Answer (score 2):

Since both A and B are 0V, 0V-0V=0V difference between them. The difference does not exceed threshold of logic 1 or logic 0 (+0.2V or -0.2V) so the fail-safe mechanism keeps the RO high.

Comment: how can i create difference of  A-B = 0.2v  between pins A and B?